# Is this a valid way to prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists y \in \mathbb{R} \ 4x + 3y = 6$?

Tags: solution-verification

Attempt:

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $4x + 3y = 6$.  $$\Rightarrow y =
>  \frac{6 - 4x}{3} = 2 - \frac{4x}{3}.$$ Thus, we have found a
> real number $y$ for every real number $x$ s.t $4x + 3y = 6$ and conclude that
> $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}, \ 4x + 3y = 6$.

This seems too simple to be right. Am I on the right track?

Comment: To prove $\forall x \, \exists y \dots$, start by assuming that $x$ is given. Then state what $y$ is or how you can find it. Finally prove the property that is supposed to hold for $x$ and $y$. It's like a tennis game: Somebody serves you the $x$, show that you can always return the serve (find a $y$ with the desired property.) Your attempt has all the right formulae, but it does not follow this logical scheme.

Comment: You can prove by solving, I suppose.  The real issue is *how* were the real numbers defined for you.  To my mind, part of the definition of $\mathbb R$ is that $\mathbb R$ is a field (do you know what that means?).  As such any $ax + by =c$ will have solutions (unless both $a,b=0$ and $c$ doesn't>

Comment: To be logically impeccable, plug this value in for $y$ and verify that it is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this simple, since addition and multiplication preserve elements in $\mathbb{R}$ (unless you are dividing by zero). So $y$ is a real number.